# In Qt, while using the hide() or setVisible(false) how do I stop a child grid layout from trying to centre everything?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

What I really want to do is to tell it to NOT move things around when setVisible(true) or setVisible(false) is called. How can I do this?

Comment: The Qt forums may be a better place for this question.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: why exactly wouldn't SO be a good place for this question?

Comment: @peppe: I didn't say that SO would not be a good place.  I said that the Qt forums may be a *better* place.  They would be a better place because this question is more about Qt specifics and the forums are where more Qt experts hang out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`QSizePolicy::setRetainSizeWhenHidden`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#setRetainSizeWhenHidden):

> void QSizePolicy::setRetainSizeWhenHidden(bool retainSize)
>
> Sets whether a layout should retain the widget's size when it is hidden. If retainSize is true, the layout will not be changed by hiding the widget.

In other words:

```
QSizePolicy p = widget->sizePolicy();
p.setRetainSizeWhenHidden(true);
widget->setSizePolicy(p);
```

Comment: This is precisely in line with my question. Thank you.
To be super specific, I have a gridLayout set up but when I attempt to do a gridLayout->sizePolicy(), it tells me that gridLayout does not have any member by that name. There is sizeHint() and sizeConstraint() but no sizePolicy(). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Call this on the widget you put *in* the grid layout (i.e. the widget you want to hide and whose space you want to keep). Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: The right side is when everything is visible and the left is with some hidden with hide(). 
https://postimg.org/image/nz1wsdf7r/
I want the labels to hold position and not move around like that.
I tried what you said on all those labels and spinBoxes but this is the result.
P.S. All the labels and the spinBoxes are inside a gridLayout.

Comment: [Update] For whatever reason, it refused to work when i did it by code, I went ahead and did the exact same thing on my labels and spinBoxes in Qt Creator and it all works fine now. Thank you!